# Meteor: Accessing a capped collection that has been created by an external program

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I’m dealing with a “C” program that creates MongoDB collections as capped collections and I'm trying to access these collections from Meteor and get documents from them.

If I use "new Mongo.Collection()", the client doesn't see the collections as capped and keeps caching the documents beyond the number of them actually existing on the server. For example the collections on the server are capped to have no more than 10 documents in them and I made sure that there is no more than 10 documents in the collections on the server but the client keeps showing the documents being added to so I end up more than 10 documents on the client and their number keeps growing.

I can't call "createCollection" with {capped:true} because I'm getting error saying that the createCollection cannot be called on a collection that is already existing.

I was wondering if there is a way to access capped collections from Meteor that are created by some other code and still see them as capped collections with the actual limited documents in them without client keeping growing the cached documents beyond the capped limit ending up showing more documents on the client side than what actually exists on the server.

Comment: Have a look at this meteor issue, it might help https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1478